# numero random que solo se genere una vez

Tags: python, random

quiero generar un numero random con el siguiente orden si alguien me puede ayudar gracias

-generar numero random

-guardar el valor del numero random

-volver a iterar el codigo sin que se vuelva a generar un numero nuevo y se mantenga el valor del numero generado en la iteracion anterior

ejemplo

```
a = random.randin(0,4)
b = a
print(b)
```

en este caso en cada iteracion el valor de "b" cambia, lo que yo quiero es que una vez generado su primer valor este se mantenga

Comment: Hola Erick, la he marcado como duplicada, pero si tienes cualquier problema no dudes en comentar. En mi respuesta a esa pregunta, si por ejemplo quieres genrar números del 1 al 100 sin repetición solo debes hacer `gen = aleatorio(lrange(1, 101))` si usas la versión con el generador, si usas directamente `sample` sería `numeros = random.sample(range(1, 100), cantidad)`. Un saludo.

Comment: hola , mi pregunta no era esa alguien me la edito pero gracias por no sancionarme, volvere a formular mi pregunta

Comment: Hola Erick, no hagas otra, edita esta y aclara bien lo que buscas, el cierre por duplicado se puede revertir  sin problemas si realmente no lo es. Con aclarar me refiero a "al volver a iterar el codigo el numero no se vuelve a generar y mantiene su valor del generado en la iteración anterior ". Según entiendo, al iterar no se debe generar un nuevo número, sino reusar el generado antes, bien el tema está ¿a que llamas iterar exactamente? ¿Un bucle? ¿volver a llamar a una función? ¿Ejecutar un módulo de nuevo? Intenta agregar un [mcve] que ilustre más o menos lo que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias ya la edite, vi tu mensaje antes y ya habia creado otra pregunta pero ya la elimine, iterar me refiero cada vez que vuelvo a ejecutar el codigo

Comment: La edición que modifico el contenido de tu pregunta la autorizaste o aprobaste tu según el historial, consejo hay que prestar más atención al detalle la próxima amigo

Comment: Ok, gracias. La he reabierto, efectivamente la edición previa alteraba  significativamente tu planteamiento inicial.  Bien, en cuanto a tu problema, efectivamente cada vez que ejecutes esas línea esas código a `a` se le asigna un nuevo número y a `b` se le asigna el valor de `a`, para que esto no pase , al menos `b` debe almacenarse fuera de la "iteración".

Comment: Lamento haber cambiado el significado de la pregunta, sin embargo fue para intentar aclarar lo que estabas preguntando. StackOverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas que tiene cierta expectativa de esfuerzo de claridad en la preguntas para poder dar buenas respuestas.

Comment: La solución depende primordialmente del contexto, es decir, de a lo que te refieras con iteración exactamente, no es lo mismo que se trate de un ciclo (bastaría con declarar `b` fuera y usar un condicional) a que se trate de una función o método de clase o que se trate de  que cada vez que ejecutes el módulo si `b` ya tiene un valor no se genere otro (en este caso necesitaríamos almacenamiento persistente). Por eso sería bueno que agregaras algo de más contexto y especifique dónde se ejecuta ese código exactamente y a que te refieres con iteración exactamente,

Comment: muchas gracias se trataba del primer caso, ya puede encontrar la solucion con tu respuesta gracias